# Connecting to a web server in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, websocket

I am trying to connect to a web server in Python 3 and it just doesn't work!
I wrote the following in my code editor VS Code and btw, I don't have telnet installed.
So, here's my code:

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('http://data.pr4e.org',80))
```

And the traceback I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you doing this at such a low level on purpose? There are built-in and third-party modules that speak HTTP.

Comment: In any case, I don't think you should be including `http://`. Try just `data.pr4e.org`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying name lookup fails, and for good reason. When using raw sockets, you mustn't put the `http://` protocol in the hostname string.

```
mysock.connect(('http://data.pr4e.org', 80))
```

must be

```
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
```